# Django and foreign key

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I'm trying to make a blog in one page : articles and comments are on the same page. It's to understand how Django work with foreign key.

Actually, I can display all articles on the same page, but I don't know how to display each comments for each articles because I don't know how to get the good comments id associated with the good article id.

model.py :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Article(models.Model):
    titre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    auteur = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    contenu = models.TextField(null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de parution")

class Commentaire(models.Model):
    auteur = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    contenu = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False, verbose_name="Date de parution")
    article = models.ForeignKey('Article')
```

views.py :

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from blog.models import Article, Commentaire

# Create your views here.
def actualite(request, id):
    article = Article.objects.all()
    commentaire_article = Commentaire.objects.filter(article=**ARTICLE ID ???**)

    return render(request, 'blog/templates/home.html', locals())
```

template home.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <h1>Liste des articles :</h1>
    {% for article in article %}
        <li>
            Titre : {{ article.titre }}<br />
            Contenu : {{ article.contenu }}<br />
            Auteur : {{ article.auteur }}<br />
            Date : {{ article.date }}<br />
            Commentaire : 
            {% for commentaire_article in commentaire_article %}
            <ul>
                <li>
                    De : {{ commentaire_article.auteur }}<br />
                    {{ commentaire_article.contenu|default:"Aucun commentaire" }}
                </li>
            </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        </li>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to add `commentaire_article` in the view/ template. You can access comments of each articles by accessing its reverse `ForeignKey`.

You can access comments of articles by `article.commentaire_set.all()`.

In your view, do something like this

```
def actualite(request, id):
    articles = Article.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'blog/templates/home.html', {'articles': articles})
```

**I see no use of passing `id` to the view because you are listing all articles. If want to display only one article, you can use `.get()` instead.**

In your template, write something like this to get comments.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <h1>Liste des articles :</h1>
    {% for article in articles %}
        <li>
            Titre : {{ article.titre }}<br />
            Contenu : {{ article.contenu }}<br />
            Auteur : {{ article.auteur }}<br />
            Date : {{ article.date }}<br />
            Commentaire : 
            {% for commentaire_article in article.commentaire_set.all %}
            <ul>
                <li>
                    De : {{ commentaire_article.auteur }}<br />
                    {{ commentaire_article.contenu|default:"Aucun commentaire" }}
                </li>
            </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        </li>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```